# Is it possible to combine expressions with static strings in angular attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried to do create a string that consists of static parts and angularjs expressions / scope variables and filters:

`BackupText__{{name}}_{{date | date:'yyyyMMdd_HHmm'}}.txt`
in my template it renders fine:
`BackupText__Frank_20150101_0100.txt`
but i would like to use this generated string in directive attribute: `filename`

```
<a 
    class="button" 
    id="saveOutput" 
    href="#output_text" 
    mysaveasfilebutton 
    datacontent="output_text" 
    filename="'BackupText__' + name + '_' + date|date:'yyyyMMdd_HHmm' + '.txt'"
    title="save as: BackupText__{{name}}_{{date | date:'yyyyMMdd_HHmm'}}.txt"
>
        Save as File<br/>
        BackupText__{{name}}_{{date | date:'yyyyMMdd_HHmm'}}.txt
</a>
```

i have [created a Plunker to test it out](http://plnkr.co/edit/EpQSxg?p=preview).
(Stackoverflow Code snippet did not work / like my angular app?)

how to include the filtered date in the filename attribute value?
the example breaks at the date filter..

i like the idea to build the string in the view because it is just a 'additional option' for the user.
i think another option would be to edit the directive to allow a array for `filename` that will be concatenated internal.
are there other ways to do this 'the angular way' ?

Comment: What is not working in your example?

Comment: not sure what you want to do, how do you want to use filename?

Comment: Yes to your question. I don't see your problem.

Comment: sorry - i have updated my question to clearly state what is not working. - the date filter breaks the thing

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by try and error:
(after i had not found any hint in the documentation or here on so i tried all different formating things that came to my mind.. )

```
<a 
    class="button" 
    id="saveOutput" 
    href="#output_text" 
    mysaveasfilebutton 
    datacontent="output_text" 
    filename="'BackupText__' + name + '_' + (mydate|date:'yyyyMMdd_HHmm') + '.txt'"
    title="save as: BackupText__{{name}}_{{mydate| date:'yyyyMMdd_HHmm'}}.txt"
>
        Save as File<br/>
        BackupText__{{name}}_{{mydate| date:'yyyyMMdd_HHmm'}}.txt
</a>
```

sometimes its just this one thing you don't have tried.... ;-)

the solution is to pack an 'subexpression with filter' in `()` as in `(mydate|date:'yyyy')`
than it is allowed in an combined string.

if someone has some additional information why this works it would be great to read about!

i updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EpQSxg?p=preview)